# Blotches on my cast iron pan

Tags: cast-iron, maintenance

I am seeing blotches on my cast iron pan.
[image]
Are these just water stains after the pan has been dried by heating on the stove top? Or do I need to season my pan more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, it looks to me like oil that hasn't fully dried/burnt. If you put it on a hot hob whilst dry for a couple of minutes it'll be easy to check. If it blackens, you're fine